# Show that the probability of never hitting 0 on a birth-death chain is $6/\pi^2$.

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

In the question we have a birth-death chain on $\{0,1,2,...\}$ whose only non-zero transitions from $i$ are to $i+1$ and $i-1$, with probabilities $p_i$ and $q_i$, respectively. I have that $p_i$ and $q_i$ are positive for all $i\ge1$, and $h_i$ is the probability of reaching $0$ starting from $i$.

If we write $$\gamma_i  = \prod_1^{i-1}{\frac {q_i}{p_i}}$$ it can be shown by iteration that $h_i = 1-(1-h_1)\sum_{k=1}^i{\gamma_k}$. I now have a case where $$p_i=\left(\frac {i+1}{i}\right)^2 q_i$$ and I need to show that if $X_0=1$, then $\mathbb{P}(X_n \ge1 \text{ for all } n\ge1) = 6/\pi^2$. I can see clearly that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\gamma_k}=\frac {\pi^2}{6}$$ but I'm not really sure how to progress beyond there. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I have doubts about your formula for $h_i$. I think the derivation of it should produce:

\begin{align}
h_i &= \dfrac{\sum\limits_{k=i}^{\infty} \rho_k}{1 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \rho_k} \qquad\text{ where } \rho_k = \dfrac{q_1\cdots q_k}{p_1\cdots p_k} = \prod_{j=1}^k\left(\dfrac{j}{j+1}\right)^2 = \dfrac{1}{(k+1)^2},\;k\geq 1 \\
\end{align}

A reference for this is [here](https://cs.nyu.edu/mishra/COURSES/09.HPGP/scribe4) or Karlin and Taylor's *Introduction to Stochastic Modeling*.

The required probability is:

\begin{align}
1-h_1 &= \dfrac{1}{1 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \rho_k} \\
& \\
&= \dfrac{1}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{k^2}} \\
& \\
&= \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}} \\
& \\
&= \dfrac{6}{\pi^2}.
\end{align}

Comment: Having now gone through the problem, my formula for $h_i$ was indeed correct, although the derivation of the answer you have referred to leads to the same, correct result. Thanks!

Comment: @Exp5LogMingus Ok, I'll re-check it. Is it from a book or notes? Can you give a reference? Thanks.

Comment: @Exp5LogMingus Yes, I think your formula is OK, although the definition of $\gamma_i$ is not great. $\gamma_1$ isn't well-defined - it should be $1$. Also, it uses $i$ for two purposes. Maybe it should be: $\gamma_i=\prod\limits_{j=1}^{i-1}\dfrac{q_j}{p_j},\; i\geq 2$.