# How to calculate probability of ultimate extinction of a birth-death process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, birth-death-process

Consider a birth-death process on $\mathbb{N}_0$ with transition probabilities given by $$p_{0, 1} = 1, p_{i, i - 1} + p_{i, i + 1} = 1, p_{i, i + 1} = \left(\frac {i + 1} i\right)^2p_{i, i - 1}, i \geq 1.$$ Assuming $X_0 = 0$, calculate the probability of the event $$\{X_n \geq 1\ \forall\ n \geq 1\}.$$

Hint: $$\sum^{\infty}_{m = 1} \frac 1 {m^2} = \frac {\pi^2} 6.$$

**My thoughts**

Firstly, I know that starting at $X_0 = 0$ is equivalent to starting at $X_1 = 1$. Secondly, it is also trivial to obtain $$p_{i, i - 1} = \frac {i^2} {(i + 1)^2 + i^2}$$ and $$p_{i, i + 1} = 1 - \frac {i^2} {(i + 1)^2 + i^2}.$$

**Edit**

Following a comment below, since we already know it is irreducible, I think one way to proceed would be to determine whether the chain is transient or recurrent.

Now, define $$\gamma_0 = 1$$ and $$\gamma_y = \frac {\prod\limits^y_{i = 1} p_{i, i - 1}} {\prod\limits^y_{i = 1} p_{i, i + 1}}\ \forall\ y \geq 1.$$ From what I was taught, the chain will be recurrent if and only if $$\sum^{\infty}_{z = 0} \gamma_z = \infty.$$

However, I am not sure how to proceed. Am I even on the right track here?

As my professor has only briefly touched on birth-death processes and this is my first time encountering such a problem, any intuitive suggestions will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Check [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1578425/show-that-the-probability-of-never-hitting-0-on-a-birth-death-chain-is-6-pi2?rq=1)

Comment: @Tab1e Thank you so much once again! I have solved it :) Weird how I was looking high and low for references to a similar problem, but I was not able to find the post you had linked. You are really doing a great service to this community!